# How to Write object to stream without using BinaryFormatter?

Tags: c#

I use BinaryWriter to write my items to stream. How i can write object to Stream and back without BinaryFormatter?

Comment: Use an XmlFormatter :-D

Comment: =) XmlFormatter is too slow...

Comment: Well why don't you want to use `BinaryFormatter`? What are your actual requirements here?

Comment: Write your own formatter or use other available options

Answer (score 1):

Simply, you need to (one of):

- write code that (de)serializes each field/property in turn, using the (reader/)writer API over each member
- write code that *automates* the first option at compile-time, generating C#
- write code that *automates* the first option at runtime, generating IL (or C# which it compiles)

Taking into account nested objects, nulls, reference-tracking, collections, lists, serialization callbacks, string value-vs-reference equality, conversion operators, custom iterators, surrogates, serialization-contexts, IO buffering, etc.

Alternatively, use one of the many binary serializers that exist that already do that. I'm hugely biased as the author, but I'd use protobuf-net.

Answer (score 0):

My biased answer is http://binaryserializer.codeplex.com.

It allows you to define bindings to control the exact format of the data.